# How to avoid further search on a vertex's neighbour in BFS? I'm using Boost Graph Library

Tags: c++, boost, graph, breadth-first-search

I need to avoid pushing a vertex into the queue if it doesn't fit a certain condition, thus preventing further search on its neighbours. What should I write in my custom visitor, or should I modify something elsewhere? Codes in detail will be appreciated.

Comment: "Codes in detail will be appreciated." is a very funny constraint given the complete lack of code in the question

Comment: Do you mean you don't want to traverse a node at all? Are you looking for a path or for a target?

Comment: I'm not looking for a path nor a target. I just want to "expand" from the source vertex to the maximum extent. I will do some other job in the visitor.

Comment: @sehe See my recent answer for update, if it doesn't bother.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I used an alternative solution: Rewrite the BFS algorithm instead of inherit one from Boost. The original BFS code in Boost is simple to understand that even I can copy and modify from it.